# ClassNotFoundException - javax.naming.NamingException rror in ejb with wildfly 29

Tags: java, ejb, wildfly, javabeans

I'm a beginner with java bean and especially in enterprise java bean
So I read a little bit of documentation and created a simple server app and deployed it using wildfly 29

Then I made a client app to test it
But this error occured :

```
Oct 06, 2023 1:36:10 PM org.jboss.logmanager.JBossLoggerFinder getLogger
ERROR: The LogManager accessed before the "java.util.logging.manager" system property was set to "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager". Results may be unexpected.
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to lookup [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mamisa.MamisoaRemote]
        at org.wildfly.naming.client.util.NamingUtils.namingException(NamingUtils.java:171)
        at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteClientTransport.lookup(RemoteClientTransport.java:291)
        at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteContext.lambda$lookupNative$0(RemoteContext.java:190)
        at org.wildfly.naming.client.NamingProvider.performExceptionAction(NamingProvider.java:222)
        at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteContext.performWithRetry(RemoteContext.java:100)
        at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteContext.lookupNative(RemoteContext.java:188)
        at org.wildfly.naming.client.AbstractFederatingContext.lookup(AbstractFederatingContext.java:74)
        at org.wildfly.naming.client.store.RelativeFederatingContext.lookupNative(RelativeFederatingContext.java:58)
        at org.wildfly.naming.client.AbstractFederatingContext.lookup(AbstractFederatingContext.java:74)
        at org.wildfly.naming.client.AbstractFederatingContext.lookup(AbstractFederatingContext.java:60)
        at org.wildfly.naming.client.AbstractFederatingContext.lookup(AbstractFederatingContext.java:66)
        at org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyRootContext.lookup(WildFlyRootContext.java:144)
        at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409)
        at App.main(App.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mamisa.MamisoaRemote
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractClassResolver.loadClass(AbstractClassResolver.java:129)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractClassResolver.resolveProxyClass(AbstractClassResolver.java:141)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadClassDescriptor(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1036)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1381)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:298)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:231)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectInput.readObject(AbstractObjectInput.java:41)
        at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteClientTransport.lookup(RemoteClientTransport.java:275)
        ... 12 more
```

The server code

```
package com.mamisa;
import jakarta.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface MamisoaRemote{
    public void hello();
}
```

```
package com.mamisa;
import jakarta.ejb.Remote;
import jakarta.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class Mamisoa implements MamisoaRemote{
    @Override
    public void hello() {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

I deployed it by making it as a jar and deployed it into the wildfly server
then I made the following client app

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

import com.mamisa.MamisoaRemote;

public class App{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
        final Hashtable jndiProperties = new Hashtable();
        jndiProperties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory");
        jndiProperties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote+http://127.0.0.1:8080/");

        Context context = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);
        MamisoaRemote mr = (MamisoaRemote) context.lookup("mamisosa/Mamisoa!com.mamisa.MamisoaRemote");
        mr.hello();
    }
}
```

Thanks for help, I'm a beginner

Comment: How did you launch the main `App` entry point?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins

By launching it with every classpath of wildfly, it's probably not the way but I forced it a little bit

 java -cp "$(printf %s: ~/Downloads/wildfly-29.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/**/*.jar)":"$(printf %s: ./lib/**/*.jar)" App

Comment: That is a very large class path if you're loading all the modules. Basically what it's saying though is that whatever library contains `com.mamisa.MamisoaRemote` is not on your class path.

Answer (score 1):

You need com.mamisa.MamisoaRemote on you client classpath

Comment: It is, I put every modules of wildfly in its classpath and I jarred com.mamisa.MamisoaRemote and put it in its classpath...